# ¿Como imprimir más de 127 elementos con var_dump()?

Tags: php

Quiero imprimir un array asociativo de `500` elementos usando  `var_dump()`.

El problemas es que no me imprime los `500` solo imprime hasta el `127` y no me muestras los demás.

¿Hay alguna forma de ver los demás elementos?

Comment: ¿Seguro que hay 500 elementos? ¿Y si pruebas con `print_r`?. También haz esto: `echo count($array);`.  Te dirá **cuántos elementos hay en realidad.**

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que establecer las variables xdebug:

```
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', 5);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_children', 2048);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data', 2024);

var_dump($x);
```

para mostrar más de los 127.

[+ info - xdebug.org (english)](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings)

Comment: No sabía que `var_dump` tenía límites y menos que fuera tan poquito el límite... interesante.

Comment: wow no sabia...funciono de maravilla gracias..

Answer (score 0):

Como información adicional a la respuesta de *aldanux*, si usas *apache* y te interesa configurarlo desde *.htaccess* es similar.

```
php_value xdebug.var_display_max_depth 10
php_value xdebug.var_display_max_children 1024
php_value xdebug.var_display_max_data 1024
```

> Un apunte, si la máquina que usas no tiene mucha memoria, y el *array*, como el de un objeto por ejemplo, contiene bastante información, configurar unos valores altos puede hacer que el navegador tarde en responder o directamente se bloquee.

Comment: lo tendre en cuenta gracias